# Primefaces blockUI to block a DataTable doesn't work when the DataTable is updated via AJAX

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a DataTable in Primefaces 3.5 like so,

```
<p:panel id="dataTablePanel" toggleable="true" toggleOrientation="horizontal" closable="false" header="Data">
    <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="row" value="#{bean}"
                 lazy="true"
                 pageLinks="10"
                 paginator="true"
                 sortMode="multiple"
                 resizableColumns="true"
                 sortOrder="descending"
                 editable="true"
                 filterEvent="keyup"
                 selection="#{bean.selectedValues}"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                 rows="10"
                 rowKey="#{row.id}"
                 rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                 editMode="row">

                 ...
    </p:dataTable>
</p:panel>
```

I'm using a [`<p:blockUI>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/blockUI.jsf)  as follows to block this DataTable while some operations on this DataTable are being performed.

```
<p:blockUI block="dataTable" trigger="dataTable">
    Loading<br />
    <p:graphicImage value="../resources/images/ajax_loader_image/ajax-loader.gif"/>
</p:blockUI>
```

This works fine.

---

I'm using a `<p:commandButton>` which when pressed causes a row to be inserted into the database and consequently the DataTable is updated via AJAX (this button is held by another panel with the id attribute `id="panel"` and some necessary UIComponents like `<p:inputText>` and so on).

```
<p:commandButton 
               id="btnSubmit" 
               update="dataTable panel" 
               actionListener="#{bean.insert}" 
               icon="ui-icon-check" 
               value="Save"/>
```

When a row is added, the DataTable is updated and `<p:blockUI>` doesn't work afterwords. Why does this happen?

---

Therefore, I'm temporarily blocking the panel which the DataTable is contained in like so,

```
<p:blockUI block="dataTablePanel" trigger="dataTable">
    Loading<br />
    <p:graphicImage value="../resources/images/ajax_loader_image/ajax-loader.gif"/>
</p:blockUI>
```

In this case, `block="dataTable"` has been changed to `block="dataTablePanel"`.

Why isn't the DataTable alone blocked after it is updated via AJAX?

Comment: Try solution proposed in next answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12392819/2881869 .
It fixed described problem for me.

Comment: Honestly saying, there is not an exact duplicate question. `<p:blockUI>` didn't work for me anyway. I instead used [PrimeFaces Extension](http://primefaces-extensions.github.io/) [`<pe:blockUI>`](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/blockui/blockUIAjax.jsf) that functions properly after `DataTable` is updated via AJAX.