# p:blockUI remains blocked after Ajax call completes

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am utilizing the PrimeFaces toolkit in my Java/JSF application.  I have a couple of spots in the app where I will execute some relatively long running web service calls.  I want to prevent the user from double submitting the call while also presenting some kind of indication that "something" is happening and to wait and be patient.

To accomplish this, I have used the PrimeFaces component called 'BlockUI'.  It does exactly what I need it to do, however, implementing this with my already existing validation messages and markup is presenting a problem.

The problem is that once the ajax call tied to the button press is finished, the blocked portion of the UI remains blocked, even after an error message has been rendered underneath.  Below is the code relevant to the button markup:

```
<h:panelGroup id="formNC3EditPageCenterBox" layout="block"
    class="centerBox">

    <h:panelGroup id="formNC3EditPageFormGroup" layout="block">

        <h:form id="formNC3Form">

            <h:panelGroup id="errorMessageContainer" layout="block"
                rendered="#{facesContext.isValidationFailed()}">
                <h:panelGrid id="errorMessageGrid" columns="2">
                    <h:graphicImage name="images/error.png" alt="error icon" />
                    <h:messages class="requiredLabel" layout="table" globalOnly="true" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="formNC3SaveAndCancelButtonGroup"
                class="centerButtonContainer">
                <p:commandButton id="formNC3SaveButton" value="#{labels.save}"
                    actionListener="#{stateAnnualFormManagedBean.save()}"
                    update="formNC3Form" />

                <h:outputText value="&#160;" />
                <h:commandButton id="formNC3CancelButton" value="#{labels.cancel}"
                    action="#{stateAnnualFormManagedBean.handleCancelAction()}"
                    ajax="false" />
                <p:blockUI widgetvar="block" block="formNC3EditPageCenterBox"
                    trigger="formNC3SaveButton" animate="false">
                    <h:graphicImage name="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="ajax-loader" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{labels.processing}" />
                </p:blockUI>
            </h:panelGroup>

        </h:form>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Note that this is not the entirety of the page but all the functionally relevant pieces are present.  Below are the relevant sections of the Java backing bean:

```
//I call a 'save' method which executes a web service call in a try block

try {
  webservice.call(pseudocode);
} catch (ValidationException vx) {
  // if validation errors are returned I set something in the faces messages
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
        message.setSummary(PageUtilities
                .fetchMessage("some.package.name", messageKey, null));
        message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        context.addMessage(null, message);
        context.validationFailed();
        context.renderResponse();
} catch (WebServiceException wx) {
  // if the webservice call fails i also set a message
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
        message.setSummary(PageUtilities
                .fetchMessage("some.package.name", messageKey, null));
        message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        context.addMessage(null, message);
        context.validationFailed();
        context.renderResponse();
}
```

So, ultimately what happens is this, I click on the submit button, the block UI goes into effect blocking the view of the page.  The webservice call ends, in my case right now it is failing.  The block UI body disappears, the web service error is rendered at the top of the page - however - the block UI 'graying-out' of the targeted component remains.  I cannot click on anything after that, the interface is still 'blocked'.

I suspect this has something to do with the order in which items are being updated to the UI but I am not intimate enough with the JSF life cycle, especially once adding ajax and PrimeFaces, to know where to look for the error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is screenshot with some of the less important information removed.  You can see the error was rendered, but the UI remains 'blocked'

[image]

** Note - I should mention that when I target the button panel id `formNC3SaveAndCancelButtonGroup` the block UI component works 100% perfectly.  My only gripe about this is that the component 'body' shows up over the button container and the 'grayed-out' area is only over the button container.  This is understandable of course, but I'd like the animation and the grayed out area to appear, if not over the whole body, at least the content area of the web application.

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390985/primefaces-blockui-stops-working-after-ajax-update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomek - your suggestion was correct.  this was related to trying to update the same node twice, I moved the block UI to block only a portion of the page and it worked properly

"The trigger attribute binds jQuery listeners on the specified elements. However if you update an element the binding gets lost. I don't know if it works, but you could try moving the