# p:blockui disable ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem, I'm using `p:blockUi` to block the full body of my page. The problem is that the AJAX events stopped to work, actually they only work once and then never again.

¿Does anybody now how I can fix it?

Here is my code:

```
<h:form id="formMenu">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><p:commandLink action="alta" value="Alta" id="btn_alta"/></li>  
        <li><p:commandLink  value="Tramitaci&oacute;n" id="btn_tramitacion"/></li>  
        <li><p:commandLink  value="Bajas" id="btn_baja"/></li>  
        <li><p:commandLink  action="salir" value="Salir" id="btn_salir"/></li>          
    </ul>

    <p:blockUI block=":full_page" trigger="btn_alta,btn_salir,btn_tramitacion,btn_baja">
      <h:panelGrid columns="1">  
        <h:graphicImage value="/resources/img/ajaxloadingbar.gif" 
                        style="horizontal-align:middle; vertical-align: middle;"/>  
        <h:outputText value="Cargando..." style="white-space: nowrap;"/>  
        </h:panelGrid>
  </p:blockUI>
</h:form>
```

Comment: why is there an ajax="false" on the `p:blockUI`? And any errors on the browser console?

Comment: just trying options I change it from true to false and its neither working. No console error.

Comment: Sorry, I meant why is there an ajax attribute at all (it is not supported) afaik. And if there are no errors, I have no idea, it just works for me. (on what element is 'full_page' the id?)

Comment: and where is the 'widgetVar' part that you refer to in your title?

Comment: You are right im not using a widget var, i used yesterday, i have edited the question. Full_page is the id that im giving to my body component in the template, so i block everything. The ajax property wasnt here im just trying options because i saw in this post they are using it in commandbuttons but im a newbie in primefaces and i have no idea hoe to fix it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390985/primefaces-blockui-stops-working-after-ajax-update

Anyway thank you very much

Comment: Solved using AjaxStatus http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39897415/can-use-ajaxstatus-while-the-next-page-is-loading?noredirect=1&lq=1